# How to locate image before list?

Tags: html, css

**Hi I have a list that is compromised of 5 items and a little photo. I want "foto.png" to sit before list.**

Now it looks like this:-

[image]

What I want to do is:
[image]

Here is my code below:-

```css
 .headerbar {
     text-align: right;
     padding-top: 10px;
    
    }
    .profilephoto {
     float: right;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .headerbar li {
     color: white;
     display: inline;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 7.5px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 18.5px;
     font-family: "Dosis", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .headerbar li:last-child {
     margin-right: 7.5px;
     color: #ff5f5f;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="headerbar">
         <div class="profilephoto"><img src="/img/foto.png" width="60"></div>
         <ul>
       <li><a href="#"> Profile</a></li>
                <li><img src="/img/messages.png" width="18"> <a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                <li><img src="/img/notification.png" width="18"> <a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">&#8226; &#8226; &#8226;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">QUIT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you give a fiddle link?

Comment: You have the photo div floating right, just change it to float left

Comment: Whats the reason you dont place the profilephoto in the ul as a list item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are floating foto.png to right...
Float both, `.profilephoto` and `ul`,  to `left`, instead to `right`.

Comment: When I convert  float right to left the picture goes to absolute left near logo.

Comment: So add some `margin-left` to the `headerbar`, or just only to the `.profilephoto`... Depending on your needs.

Comment: Also what Sven B and Zeev Katz are suggesting is a good idea if it fits to you...

Comment: Instead doing this I gave headerbar width and I changed float right to left. Now, it's working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Place the image in the list.

```
<div class="headerbar">
        <ul>
            // picture added here
            <li><img src="/img/foto.png" width="60"></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Profile</a></li>
            <li><img src="/img/messages.png" width="18"> <a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            <li><img src="/img/notification.png" width="18"> <a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&#8226; &#8226; &#8226;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">QUIT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

You dont have to use floats this way and can ommit the prophilephoto css class.

You can still add margins by applying it to the li like:

```
 <li style="margin-left:20px;"><img src="/img/foto.png"  ></li>
```

or add a class to the li

```
 <li class="profilepic"><img src="/img/foto.png"  ></li>
```

and in css:

```
.profilepic{
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Thx. But I'll set different margin value for image and list items that's why I need something different.

Comment: @Mehmet you can still give margins, just add them to the li item with the image.

Answer (score 2):

I think just changing the following should do the trick.
Before:

```
.profilephoto {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To:

```
.profilephoto {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use float in this case, you have an `display: inline-block;` property for this issues.

---

**Change this:**

```
.profilephoto {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**To this:**

```
.profilephoto {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.headerbar {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 10px;

}
.profilephoto {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.headerbar li {
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 7.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18.5px;
    font-family: "Dosis", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.headerbar li:last-child {
    margin-right: 7.5px;
    color: #ff5f5f;
}
```

```html
    <div class="headerbar">
        <ul>
        <div class="profilephoto"><img src="/img/foto.png" width="60"></div>
            <li>
             <a href="#"> Profile</a></li>
            <li><img src="/img/messages.png" width="18"> <a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            <li><img src="/img/notification.png" width="18"> <a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&#8226; &#8226; &#8226;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">QUIT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/u1gwbyy3/)**

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to keep photo and list near each other? You can make `.profilephoto` an `inline-block` level element and float the list right, check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gkaraliunas/8b8hsnys/

Answer (score 1):

You are floating the photo to the right! So float it to the **left**:

```
.profilephoto {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: There is another image which is left on the page. Thus, when I changed it right to left it goes near the logo.

Comment: Cant see the logo in the examples you've given...? - Maybe post a more detailed example of the html and css you are working with.